# how to attach subject in json data

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, json

i want to attach the subject in json data. so, i can fetch using $.each(data.subject). below is my api code where i am fetching all the data encoding into json format. any help would be appreciated.

```
[{"id":"79","FirstName":"Elon","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Musk","Gender":"Male","Location":"New York","Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com","Mobile":"1234567890"}]
```

and want to receive like this:

```
 { "personaldetails":[{"id":"79","FirstName":"Elon","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Musk","Gender":"Male","Location":"New York","Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com","Mobile":"1234567890"}
```

this is my code;

```
    $personal = $db->prepare('select Id,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Gender,Location,Email,Mobile from personaldetails ORDER BY Id DESC');
    $personal->execute();
    $json_data=array();



    foreach($personal as $row)//foreach loop  
    {  

        $json_array['id']=$row['Id'];  
        $json_array['FirstName']=$row['FirstName'];  
        $json_array['MiddleName']=$row['MiddleName'];  
        $json_array['LastName']=$row['LastName']; 
        $json_array['Gender']=$row['Gender']; 
        $json_array['Location']=$row['Location']; 
        $json_array['Email']=$row['Email']; 
        $json_array['Mobile']=$row['Mobile'];
        array_push($json_data,$json_array);  

}  
$books = $db->prepare('select UserId,BookTitle,BookGenre,BookWriter,BookDescription from bookdetails ORDER BY UserId Desc'); 
    $books->execute();
    $json_data1=array();

     //$bookNo = 0;
    foreach($books as $row)//foreach loop  
    {  
        //$bookNo++;
        //$json_array1['BookNo']= $bookNo;  
        $json_array1['UserId']=$row['UserId']; 
        $json_array1['BookTitle']=$row['BookTitle']; 
        $json_array1['BookGenre']=$row['BookGenre'];  
        $json_array1['BookWriter']=$row['BookWriter']; 
        $json_array1['BookDescription']=$row['BookDescription']; 

    //here pushing the values in to an array  
    array_push($json_data1,$json_array1);  

}  
header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json_data);
    echo json_encode($json_data1);
    //echo json_encode($json_data1);  

?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: For this you have to use 2D array

Comment: please edit the code

Comment: added answer.Check it

Comment: [check  this! H](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438684/how-to-attach-subject-in-json-data/37439091#37439091)ope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple!

```
echo json_encode(array("yourSubject"=>$responseArray));
```

Here you can also define some other data with yourSubject like

```
code: response_code, success: true/false
```

for example

```
echo json_encode(array(
                  "yourSubject"=>$responseArray,
                  "success" => true,
                  "code" => 200,
                  "otherinfo" => "somedata"
      ));
```

that will gevi you json response like:

```
{
     "yourSubject": [{}],
      "success" : true,
      "code" : 200,
      "otherinfo" : "somedata"

}
```

in front end if this is your `data` object you can easily access data

with `data.code, data.yourSubject` and so on.

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for accepting as ans. I don't mind if you also up vote it. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 **replace this** 
   $json_array['id']=$row['Id'];  
    $json_array['FirstName']=$row['FirstName'];  
    $json_array['MiddleName']=$row['MiddleName'];  
    $json_array['LastName']=$row['LastName']; 
    $json_array['Gender']=$row['Gender']; 
    $json_array['Location']=$row['Location']; 
    $json_array['Email']=$row['Email']; 
    $json_array['Mobile']=$row['Mobile'];
    array_push($json_data,$json_array);
```

With

```
 $json_array['userprofile'] = $row;
 array_push($json_data,$json_array);
```

And echo $json_data .